django tenant local and server resolve problem
hello i develop django tenant app
in localhost when i request to ebsalar.localhost:8000 every think is ok
but when upload on server and use curl to check i got
Could not resolve host: ebsalar.localhost
local:

on server:

note: /etc/hosts same ...
need run the same in server and local

Which server do you upload to exactly?

update:
i found answer.
just add tenant.localhost to /etc/hosts
like this:
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 id-440573
127.0.0.1 ebsalar.localhost    # answer
and save
